# What is the correct way to store the data of a query inside an array in Firebase and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried storing the snapshot data inside variables and arrays, to use them in different parts of the query, but I have always encountered the problem of synchronization

```
var  RefMessage=new Firebase('https://chatfbexample.firebaseio.com/user-messages/332');
var oMessages=[];
var All= new Firebase('https://chatfbexample.firebaseio.com/all-messages');
RefMessage.on("value",function(snapshot){

        snapshot.forEach(function(snap){
            var key=snap.key();
            var mensajeR=All.child(key);
          mensajeR.on('value',function(snap){
            var id=snap.val().id;
            oMessages[id]=[];
            oMessages[id]['id']=id;
           });

        });

    for(var i in oMessages)
    {
        console.log(oMessages[i]['id']);//nothing to show
    }
    });
```

Usually, if the variables are created in the query, and are assigned the value of the snapshot, depending on the number of records in the database, so they will be shown to the user. if you want to display only one value, it will be loaded repeatedly, and if it is taken out of the query,the problem of synchrony appears.
I have researched and I have not found much information on this, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: My answer to your other very similar question describes how to tackle this using promises.

Comment: I'll take a look at the promises, I do not know much about javascript, I hope I can solve this